# JMeter insert server name or IP dynamically

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to create JMeter tests and use the same tests for different environments- QA, Staging, Dev etc. 
I want to dynamically change the IP address by either changing the CSV File or passing the value through ant script or manually through command prompt. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to do so. The Test doesn't pick up the value from CSV file or from the command prompt.

Can someone please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you get an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 15):

I usually add a HTTP Request Defaults element to the test and change it manually.

[image: Selecting an HTTP Request Defaults]

[image]

Otherwise for automation, you can modify the jmx file using a script.

**Edit** in fact, you can use ant filters to change this dynamically at build time.  For example, use a filter of `<filter token="SERVER" value="${server}"/>` and a `copy` target with filtering on the file below will get you a new jmx file which will use the correct server.

```
 <ConfigTestElement guiclass="HttpDefaultsGui" testclass="ConfigTestElement" testname="HTTP Request Defaults" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">@SERVER@</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path"></stringProp>
        </ConfigTestElement>
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped in my project maintanance.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you should place your csv file where you saved your test script file. Normally test script can be saved as with jmx extension and placed your csv file in the same directory of it.

Content of the CSV file as follows:

```
url;www.test123.com
url;www.test1234.com
url;www.test12345.com
```

Note that in the Thread Group configuration, thread count must be minimum number of lines in the csv file. According to above CSV file, we should define minimum 3 thread in the Thread Group.

After this configuration, JMeter will automatically call Http Request Defaults configuration everytime when a thread is executed.

**CSV Data Set Config**

[image]

**HTTP Request Defaults**

[image]

**HTTP Request (Only Path is set)**

[image]

**Regular Expression Extractor (Optional to find specific response)**

[image]

**Write found regex result to a file (Optional)**

[image]

Source: http://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/JMeter-Dynamically-Change-Server-Name-Using-CSV-Data-File

Answer (score 4):

Within your test you can use Jmeter properties--and then you can switch those properties from the command line.

Take a look at this section of the docs:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#using_variables

This section also is helpful:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P

If you wanted to vary the  hostname, you could follow this approach:

Define the property value in the command line:

jmeter -Jhostname1=www.realhost.edu

Fetch the value in the test itself, providing a default if none is available:

${__P(hostname,www.dummy.org)} - return value of property hostname or www.dummy.org if not defined

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/best-practices.html#user_variables), using a CSV to load variables on launch is fairly straightforward:

> Create a text file containing the user names and passwords, separated by commas. Put this in the same directory as your test plan.
>
> Add a CSV DataSet configuration element to the test plan. Name the variables USER and PASS.
>
> Replace the login name with ${USER} and the password with ${PASS} on the appropriate samplers
>
> The CSV Data Set element will read a new line for each thread

The important thing to note is the last line - perhaps you're moving on to a new thread group, but have your variables all in one line. Alternatively, having them on multiple lines for one group will also cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

The CSV data set is an easy way to changes lots of values.

If you had the desire to do it from the command line, you could set the domain and login credentials as PROPERTIES, and then define the properties from the command line